# Ошибка в Mysql (1146)

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь загрузить в БД таблицы и выходит такая ошибка (БД пустая). Подскажите как решить?

Comment: Создайте таблицу, чтобы она существовала.

Comment: Пробовал, та же ошибка выскакивает

Comment: Значит вы что-то сделали не так. Ошибка однозначно сообщает вам, что таблица `world.version` не существует.

Comment: http://rgho.st/72WSMrjms

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть в самом вопросе. Ну и таблица должна называться не `world.version` а `version`. `world` - имя бд.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что в базе `world` нет таблицы `version`. Решение тривиально -- создайте недостающую таблицу.